# Adding dynamic dropdown that use bootstrap classes for jQuery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I need to add a set of dropdown and other controls on button click. 
I used this bootsnip to achieve that:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/AXVrV

However, I'd want to use bootstrap-select on those dropdowns.

```
<select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]">
  <option value="">Date</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
</select>
```

In this innher html of div created by JavaScript, if I give the select tag "selectpicker" class to make use of `bootstrap-select`, it does not work because bootstrap-select uses a combination of divs, buttons etc. to achieve the appearance rather than select. It would be a hassle and not very dependable to recreate all those nested tags. Is there a way to achieve it in JavaScript or using repeat in Aurelia?

UPDATE: Sorry I wasn't clear. I need to repeat a set of dropdowns dynamically on a button click, rather than just the options. I have a component "list1" with following code:

```
   <div class="btn-group col-sm-4">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span id="selected"> ${list}  </span><span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li role="presentation" repeat.for="list of lists">
    <a href="#" click.delegate="somefunction()">${listName}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

This gives me a bootstrap dropdown. 
 Then I have another component "list2" with similar set of tags.
 In my view, I have

```
        <div id="mydiv">
           <list1></list1>
           <list2></list2>
        </div>
```

They are showing up nicely. Now I want to have a button that adds a set of these two dropdowns dynamically i.e.

```
 <button id="add" click.delegate="addFields()"></button>
```

In my vm, I have

```
addFields() {
 var list = document.createElement("select");
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
 div.appendChild(list);
}
```

This button adds a regular select dropdown. I want it to add the stylized dropdown components above. Do I go on adding

```
  var dd = document.createElement("button");
    dd.class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle";
```

and so on, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved this if anyone is looking for something similar. It's way simpler than I thought it would be.

In my vm, I have a variable count, which I incremented every time the add button is clicked.

```
addFields() {
this.count++;
}
```

My div in the view is now repeated for that count, which increases with every click of the button

```
 <div repeat.for="c of count">
       <list1></list1>
       <list2></list2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for you to do it, via `repeat.for`: from the view template or from the view-model

1. View template

```
<template>
  <select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]">
    <option value="">Date</option>
    <option repeat.for='year of [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]' model.bind='year'>${year}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

2. From view-model

```
export class MyClass {
  years = [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<template>
  <select class="form-control" id="educationDate" name="educationDate[]">
    <option value="">Date</option>
    <!-- notice the difference here, years instead of an array -->
    <option repeat.for='year of years' model.bind='year'>${year}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

---

For each option in your `repeat.for`, you can use `value.bind` or just omit it. Depends on the data type you wanna get. `model.bind` for `number`, without `model.bind` for `string`. Example

```html
<select value.bind='educationalYear'>
  <option value="">Date</option>
  <option repeat.for='year of [2015, 2016, 2017, 2018]'>${year}</option>
</select>
```

This case, `educationalYear` in your model will be a string.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I have updated the post above.